# how to store 100 values for an exponential distribution

Tags: r

Hermione and Ron have won prizes with random values. Hermione’s prize will be £X and Ron’s prize £Y , where X and Y are independent exponential random variables, each with expected value 1000.
Write R commands to simulate one pair of values of (X,Y) and compute R = X/Y . Create a loop to run the above commands 100 times. Store the 100 values of X in a vector Xsample, the 100 values of Y in a vector Ysample and store the ratios, R, in a vector Rsample.
Draw histograms of the data in Xsample, Ysample and Rsample.

I know that the rate is 0.001. firstly would x and y be  'rexp(0.001)'. and also for the for loop to store the 100 values of x would that be

```
for(i in 1:100)
{
i=rexp(0.001)
}
```

However, how could I use the 100 values to plot a histogram.I am very confused on what the question wants from me, to be honest, could you please explain?

Comment: Both of your answers are incorrect. Look at the help page of `rexp` carefully. In your loop, you need to store the values in a vector or list, not replace the iterating parameter, `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to generate 100 values using `rexp` and for-loop. We can create an empty vector and save the result to the vector based on indexing.

```
# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(1234)

# Create an empty vector
result <- numeric()

# Use for loop to create values and save the results
for(i in 1:100){
  result[[i]] <- rexp(n = 1, rate = 0.001)
}

# See the first six elements in the result
head(result)
# [1] 2501.758605  246.758883    6.581957 1742.746090  387.182584   89.949671

# Plot the histogram
hist(result)
```

[image]

Here is another way to generate 100 values and use for-loop. We can use `c` to repeatedly combine the result to the vector. However, notice that this method is slower than the previous one and thus the previous is the preferred way to use for-loop to save values.

```
# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(1234)

# Create an empty vector
result2 <- numeric()

# Use for loop to create values and save the results
for(i in 1:100){
  x <- rexp(n = 1, rate = 0.001)
  result2 <- c(result, x)
}

# See the first six elements in the result2
head(result2)
# [1] 2501.758605  246.758883    6.581957 1742.746090  387.182584   89.949671
```

[image]

Finally, it is important to point out that the `rexp` function has an argument `n` allow us to directly generate 100 values without the use of for-loop.

```
# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(1234)

# Generate 100 values
result3 <- rexp(n = 100, rate = 0.001)

# See the first six elements in the result3
head(result3)
# [1]  905.2344  932.1655 2296.7747   15.3926  264.8849  933.5238
```

[image]